# TypeError: 'Entry' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am building an Python with Tkinter application, and one of the things it does is take input (from Entry boxes) and saves it. However, recently it has started creating this error code in multiple places:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\paintersinventory.py", line 2773, in grabpaintingname
saveedit()
File "C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\paintersinventory.py", line 2736, in saveedit
w = str(title[pnttoedit]) + " (" + str(copyat) + ")"
TypeError: 'Entry' object is not callable
```

Here is the related code, excluding the Tkinter box that pops up to ask for the information, which exists and correctly, after a button press sends the code to the grabpaintingname def:

```
painter = {}
title = {}
names = []
pnttoedit = ''
copyat = 1

def saveedit(): 
    w = str(title[pnttoedit]) + " (" + str(copyat) + ")"
    names.append(w)
    v = painter[pnttoedit]
    painter[w] = v
    messagebox.showinfo("Painter's Inventory", "Copy of " + str(pnttoedit) + " created.")
    print(str(pnttoedit))

def grabpaintingname():
     global pnttoedit
     pnttoedit = tvkare.get()
     saveedit()

tvkare = StringVar(editers)
tvkare.set(names[0])
e2 = OptionMenu(mainframe, tvkare, *names)
e2.grid(row=3, column=1)
def change_dropdown(*args):
    pnttoedit = tvkare.get()
```

Any help with how to solve this problem or information on why it might be occurring would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you create a global variable named `str` somewhere in your code?

Comment: This does not appear to be a [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley: Yes, I did accidentally. That fixed the issue. Thank you so much. That explains why sometimes it would work and then suddenly it would freak out - I must have triggered one of the str = accidentally. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wanted to mark that it was solved by Bryan Oakley.

I had variables called str accidentally.

Comment: thanks for following up on your question, when the green tick on the left is available, consider checking it to mark your answer as accepted and clear the question from the unanswered queue.